# convert doTranslate to rtl

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, arrays, right-to-left

Hi i want help to convert this code to RTl or i mean want pixels output get Positive Not Negative

```
    doTranslate : function(pixels){
        return {
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-o-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-ms-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
            "transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px,0px)"
```

thanx

Answer (score -1):

```
    doTranslate : function (pixels) {
        return {
            "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
            "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
            "transform": "translate3d(" + -pixels + "px, 0px,0px)"
        };
```